# Treatment of 2-vinylbicyclo[2.2.2]oct-5-en-2-ol with potassium hydride

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, alcohols, pericyclic

What happens when this bicyclic compound is treated with KH in THF?

[image: Reaction scheme]

Does $\ce{KH}$ simply act as a base here? $\ce{H-}$ from $\ce{KH}$ could potentially act as a nucleophile, but I don't find any electrophilic centre in the compound. What happens?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reaction in question is one of the early examples of an **oxy-Cope** rearrangement <sup>[1]</sup> in which a 3-hydroxy-hexadiene undergoes a **[3,3]-sigmatropic rearrangement** to afford a ketone.

[image: oxy-Cope rearrangement]

The general mechanism is shown below:

[image]

<sup>**Source**: *Organic Chemistry*, Oxford University Press, 2 ed. Clayden, Warren and Greeves</sup>

In a general sense, the reaction is a [3,3]-sigmatropic rearrangement (if you look at the curly arrows, you'll see that we're essentially transposing a sigma bond from one end of the pi system to another).

The presence of the oxygen provides a driving force for the reaction, since the enol(ate) formed during the rearrangement is able to tautomerise, yielding the ketone product.

In the specific case you've given, the presence of a base means that during the sigmatropic rearrangement, the oxygen is deprotonated and therefore anionic. This specific case, using an alkoxide, is a specific kind of reaction known as an **anionic oxy-Cope**. The anion is thought to help speed up the reaction, to the extent that minimal heat is usually required.

[image]

---

**References**:

<sub>[1] *J. Am. Chem. Soc.*, **1964**, *86*,5019.  DOI: 10.1021/ja01076a067</sub>

Comment: If you want to challenge yourself further with this reaction, consider what the product would be if we substituted one of the hydrogen atoms on the vinyl group for a deuterium atom.